# How to print an X per 200 in an integer?

Tags: python

My code:

```
x = [232,  456, 1024 , 245]
x_ = []
for i in range (0, len(x)):
    while x[i] >= 200:
        x_.insert(x[i], 'X')
        x[i] = x[i] - 200
print(x_)
```

Output:
`['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']`

Wanted Output:
`['X', 'XX', 'XXXXX','X']`

I essentially want to insert an X for every 200 in the element. So if an element in the list is let's say 456, the new list will have 'XX' in x_[2].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply `'X'` with the element divided by 200:

```
x_ = ['X' * (y // 200) for y in x]
```

Comment: Thank you!

Also, quick clarifying question. How is it that you were able to do 
```'X' *  (y // 200)```? What is this operation/method called? I'm curious because essentially you're preforming an operation on a char.

Edit*: Never-mind found out about that it's simply just 'String multiplication'. I'm learning something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently inserting new `'X'` in the list instead of appending your current entry. If you want to keep your structure try:

```py
x_ = []
for i in range (0, len(x)):
    xs = 'X'
    x[i] -= 200
    while x[i] >= 200:
        xs += 'X'
        x[i] -= 200
    x_.append(xs)
print(x_)
```